# Quantum mechanics formulations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, path-integral

There are about 9 different formulations of quantum mechanics. What are the merits and setbacks of each formulation? In the path integral formulation, is the sum over all possible paths idea purely mathematical, or is it an actual probabilistic sum over trajectories?

Comment: This seem subjective. Can you elaborate on what you mean by *best?* One could ask, instead, what the merits of each formulation one are.

Comment: Which formulation gives the clearest picture of quantum mechanics in your opinion?

Comment: You can add that to the question

Comment: It's still asking for opinions, and as such is not the kind of question that is appropriate here.

Comment: I have changed the wording. Please feel free to edit the question further, if you see something necessary.

Comment: The question asks about (expert) knowledge and not (personal) opion, these two terms are too often confused or even wrongly synomymized on (Physics) SE. Voting to reopen.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretations_of_quantum_mechanics is quite detailed.